# Can I re-use my superclass's optional constructor parameter in my subclass?

Tags: c#

I have a superclass with a constructor using an optional parameter to avoid writing multiple overloaded constructors:

```
namespace Example
{
    abstract class Super
    {
        string mandatory;
        string optional;
        const string optionalDef = "default";

        public Super(string mandatory, string optional = optionalDef)
        {
            this.mandatory = mandatory;
            this.optional = optional;
        }
    }
}
```

The constructor can be called with one or two arguments, so it's like I'm implementing two overloaded constructors. Now I'm trying to "re-use" this in a subclass:

```
namespace Example
{
    class Sub : Super
    {
        public Sub(string mandatory, string optional) : base(mandatory, optional) { }

        public Sub(string mandatory) : base(mandatory) { }
    }
}
```

Since my default value is "hidden" in the superclass, I don't know how to mirror my structure from the superclass that avoids the overloaded constructors. I wanna do something like this which of course doesn't exist:

```
public Sub(string mandatory, string optional = undefined) : base(mandatory, optional) { }
```

Another thing I've tried is this:

```
public Sub(string mandatory, string optional = base.optionalDef) : base(mandatory, optional) { }
```

I think this might work if I make `optionalDef` static (which seems like a hack), but as soon as I subclass `Sub` again, it won't work anymore I think (since `base.base` isn't allowed).

Thank you!

Comment: Depending on whether or not `null` is a valid value, you could use `null` as the optional parameter in the subclass and update the base class to coalesce the parameter with the optional value. `this.optional = optional ?? optionalDef;`

Comment: Do note that "The constructor can be called with one or two arguments, so it's like I'm implementing two overloaded constructors" is explicitly not what is happening. Overloading a method is a very different mechanic from supplying an optional parameter. The value of the latter is coded in at the call site, while an overload means the caller supplies no value at all. While either mechanism can be used in many scenarios, don't make the mistake of thinking they're equivalent, and don't call methods with optional parameter values "overloaded".

Comment: In this particular case, actual overloads would give you what you want -- you can call the base constructor with one parameter if you don't want to override the default, and with two if you do. In this scheme there is no need at all for callers (be they derived classes or external clients) to know what the default value is. In general, avoid optional parameters if the optional value can't be made `default`.

Comment: Your constructor name should be `Super` not `Sprite`

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 It's actually an int parameter in my real code. But I guess I could make it a nullable int. I was thinking of that as well and I guess it would be a possible solution, but I thought there must be an easier way.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Good point, haha. I also didn't mean to make the Sub class abstract, just the Super class. I edited those things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply make `optionalDef` protected:

```
abstract class Super
{
    string mandatory;
    string optional;
    protected const string optionalDef = "default";

    public Super(string mandatory, string optional = optionalDef)
    {
        this.mandatory = mandatory;
        this.optional = optional;
    }
}

abstract class Sub : Super
{
    public Sub(string mandatory, string optional = optionalDef) : base(mandatory, optional) { }
}
```

If that's not possible for whatever reason and `null` is not a possible value, you could also use that.

Comment: Wow, I actually tried to do just that, but I still used `base.optionalDef` and it gave me an error about optionalDef not being static which confused me. Obviously, I can just leave out `base`, since it's protected and therefore just in scope. Or apparently, I'm using `base` incorrectly (since I feel both ways should be equivalent, like when you use `this` just for readability reasons), but I don't really understand why and it probably doesn't really matter. :-)

Comment: @tinymarsracing: You can't access a `static` field(and `const` is static implicitly) with  `this` or `base` because those terms are for instances only,  `this` means this instance and `base` means my parent' class instance. You can address the base const field `optionalDef` either via class name `Super.optionalDef` or just with it's name `optionalDef`.

Comment: Ohh, so it's because `const` is implicitly static. I wasn't considering that. But I guess it makes sense since it cannot be changed. Now the error I got earlier makes a lot more sense. :-) Thank you!